# Problem adding fields with Model Builder iteration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm trying to add 5 different fields to a bunch of shapefiles. I've made a model to automate it, which I'll post a picture of. It says it succeeded when it's finished running, but none of the shapefiles have the added fields in their dbf file. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The dbf files are in a subfolder of the folder I'm using for the iteration. I've made sure the recursive radio box is checked.

[image]

Comment: Your model looks ok, do you have write permission?

Comment: Yup, I do. I get no errors or anything when I run the model either.

Comment: I notice that your first Ad Field is not shaded which means it has not run, which suggests you have put in an invalid field name. Must not have spaces, start with numbers or weird characters.

Comment: I checked what I had entered into the first AddField tool. The field name is OP_GISLINK, it's a text field with max 25 characters. I might remove the iterate folder part and just make a batch input on the first AddFeild tool. I think that should work.